# VBA - Highlight columns 1 - 10 and activate column "J"

Tags: excel, vba, range, highlight, targeting

**FYI: I am using Excel 2013.**

I do twice-weekly manual sales updating which equates to 10h/week. We must manually enter data from paper to Excel, which involves constantly looking up and down and can be quite tedious and erroneous.

I have already managed to get columns A-J of the current row highlighted, but am having trouble with:

**A: Setting the default cell as column "J" (11th column across) as to be able to type the updated figure in without Shift-Tabbing every time I move to the row above/below.**

*Is there a way of setting the default cell to the far right, as a pose to the far left?*

**B: Setting a Global Macro as to be able to initiate this function on multiple spreadsheets, but not all. (Something like a hot-key initiation command).**

*I understand it must be in the 'PERSONAL.XLSB', but cannot for the life of me get it to work; is this even possible?*

*It is imperative that I do not use colour on this spreadsheet, as it is generated from the company system and certain columns contain indicative colours already.*

Please see below for my current code;

```
Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False

   With Range("a1", Target)
   Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 10)).Select
   End With

 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'this code will highlight the first 11 cells of the row
```

The reason I must highlight the entire row is due to the nature of the reporting; I must refer to 4 separate columns of data per row:

A = Destination, **B = Artist**, **C = Venue**, **D = Show-date**, E = Ticket Type, F = Allocated, G = Ticket Location, H = Last Sales Date, I = Previous Sold, **J = Total Sold** *(This is the only data that I am editing, the rest is just for reference E.G. Show name, Venue, Show-date - update total)*

Comment: You might try `Range("J:J").Select` this will allow you to not steer from J column when you enter multiple value and press Tab to select next cell.

Comment: @Vesper Thanks for the reply! Sadly, this is still not the solution as column B and Column J (of the same row) both contain data which i must refer to; if I could get column J highlighted, along with the current row by tabbing down - I'd imagine that would work.

Comment: What do you mean by default cell? If you edit a cell in a column and then press Enter selection goes to the cell below in the same column.

Comment: By default, when you code in a range - the default cell is always the top left cell. In this instance I would only like one row to be highlighted, but am having trouble amending my data as I have the far left cell (Column A) selected within my targeted range, as a pose to the far right cell (Column J). Within this selection, the enter key also does not take you to the below row.